Android Studio Ladybug - Unknown Kotlin JVM target: 21
As the title says, I've installed new Android Studio but can't compile my project anymore. After failing in kapt I have migrated everything to ksp but still no luck. I do have following configurations from day 1:
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
}

kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = "17"
}

After looking everywhere and trying multiple solutions - nothing works.
I have tried this but it DOES NOT work:


That might be factually true but I need an actionable solution - "how to" if you will. I've already tried to change the gradle JDK in Settings but nothing works.

You do have the kotlin plugin loaded into gradle?

And I found that somewhere: compileKotlin { kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_17 }

@arkascha I do have this id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") in plugins if that's what you mean.

@arkascha I guess that compileKotlin is the groovy version of what I have above in kts: kotlinOptions {jvmTarget = "17"}

I think I have sorted the issue. I'll post my answer shortly.

Why do they break AS by every release I am puzzled....

After digging for a solution I found this one working for me. Might be useful for you too.
I. For kapt:

Select Gradle JDK jbr-17



Add following configurations to your app level build.gradle.kts


android{
//...
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "17"
    }
    kotlin {
        jvmToolchain(17)
    }
//...
}

I'm guessing that's because both JDKs are under the same folder AS and gradle needs to know what version of compiler/toolchain to pick. Apparently compileOptions and kotlinOptions aren't obvious enough.
II. For ksp
Update to id("com.google.devtools.ksp") version "2.0.0-1.0.22" and kotlin id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "2.0.0". Should work without specifying jvmToolchain(17).
Also make sure that:
id("com.android.application") version "8.7.1"

I love you I love you I love you

It seems to be a misleading error message. The problem is that the kapt processing doesn't recognise JVM 21. The answer for me was to declare the android kotlin gradle plugin version explicitly in the project build.gradle, thus:
buildscript {
     repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        // ...

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:2.0.21"
        // ...


First of all  Unknown Kotlin JVM target: 21 itself says that current set target jvm is 21.
Reason: After updating android studio sometimes sets default jvm target automatically without informing / prompting and that causes the confusion.
Steps

Go to settings in android studio and select Gradle under Build, Execution, Deployment Menu as it is visible in screenshot below.



Change default jvm target to JetBrains JDK 17.0.12



Delete .gradle generated directory / folder from the project explorer in android studio.



Optionally gradle command can also be used ./gradlew clean build

Run sync project with gradle

Rebuild the project from Build -> Rebuild project


It starts working.

If you're working on an Ionic app with Capacitor and encounter issues related to text-to-image => Unknown Kotlin JVM target: 21, ensure that the Kotlin JVM target and Java versions are consistent.
In my case, I needed to explicitly set the jvmTarget to "17" in the kotlinOptions section of the build.gradle file. Here’s the configuration that worked for me:
in main build.gradle added this dependency
 buildscript {
    repositories {
       mavenCentral()
       // ...

}
dependencies {
classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.9.10"

and in the gradle of the plugin text-to-image this:
android {
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "17" // Ensure consistency with JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }
}


The sourceCompatibility and targetCompatibility specify the Java version used for compiling and running the code.
The jvmTarget in kotlinOptions must match the Java version specified above; otherwise, you might encounter runtime errors or compatibility issues.

This setup ensures that the Kotlin and Java configurations align, resolving potential issues when using Java 17 features or APIs in your project.

Had the same issue but with a different plugin. You saved me so much headache with this. Thanks!
